# Check Which Visualforce Pages Accessible?

Tags: administration, custom-permission

**`<EDIT>`**

My use case:  Rather than showing "An insufficient privileges message" after clicking on a button, I want to hide/show the button using the apex code whether to display the button based on the user's assigned `Custom Permissions`, so that preventing users from getting an  `insufficient privilege message after the` event.

**`</EDIT>`**

Is there a way to customize custom permissions for the custom objects? in the object.

What I'm trying to do is to add a new column in the Object Permission table as shown below called "Can Push" or whatever the name then let the Admin assign the access to that particular permission.

[image]

Comment: Can you go higher level? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: So on VFP we have couple of buttons that can be only accessible/available  based on certain conditions so what I'm trying to do that if I can create the custom permission access in the above custom object permission, in that way will have all the access/permissions in one place.

Comment: Still not really clear what you are going for...am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look

Comment: Are you looking for how to set `Visualforce` access? Or just how to infer it to control rendering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check via `Apex` which pages the running user can access, you just need to hit up a few configuration objects:

```
Set<Id> assigned = new Map<Id, PermissionSet>([
    SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment
        WHERE AssigneeId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
    )
]).keySet();
for (ApexPage page : [
    SELECT Name FROM ApexPage WHERE Name IN ('SiteLogin', 'CreateTask')
    AND Id IN (
        SELECT SetupEntityId FROM SetupEntityAccess
        WHERE SetupEntityType = 'ApexPage'
        AND ParentId IN :assigned
    )
]) system.debug(page.Name);
```

You could store a `Set<String> accessiblePages` collection and then inspect its contents to set properties like `canAccessPage1`, `canAccessPage2`, etc.

---

If you are trying to make `Custom Permissions` accessible in a `Visualforce Page`, the `$Permission` global variable actually tells you whether or not the running user has a specific `Custom Permission` assigned.

1. Create a `Custom Permission` for each button you wish to control.
2. Add them to `Permission Sets` as needed.
3. `Manage Assignments` for those `Permission Sets` to select which users have access.

Then your `Visualforce` would look something like:

```
<apex:commandButton ... rendered="{!$Permission.CanAccessButton1}" />
<apex:commandButton ... rendered="{!$Permission.CanAccessButton2}" />
<apex:commandButton ... rendered="{!$Permission.CanAccessButton3}" />
```